# Pinging And Accessing Computers On 1 Switch with 2 VLANs

Tags: vlan, switching

I have a 16 Port Black Box switch running 2 VLANs. Switch is setup to administer on VLAN 1 (default) at 192.168.1.52 (255.255.255.0.). Ports are as followed:

- Ports 1 - 10: VLAN 1 (Untagged) PVID 1
- Ports 11 & 12: VLAN 2 (Untagged) PVID 2
- Ports 13 - 15: VLAN 1 (Untagged) PVID 1
- Port 16: TRUNK (Tagged) PVID 1

VLAN 1 Addresses are handed out through DHCP and all machines are talking to each other.

VLAN 2 are 2 computers just setup to talk to themselves and manually addressed 
192.168.2.100 & 192.168.2.101 Respectively.

I am having a problem with VLAN 2 where the computers cannot ping or access each other even though they are addressed the same and the ports on the switch are set to VLAN 2. The switch configuration only has the VLANs setup as above as the only alteration of the default configuration. I have tired adding the configuration to this post but the system is not allowing me to add a file or copy it in as it is too big.

I am confused as to why they will not talk to each other. I have the VLAN configured correctly as I understand VLANs. What am I missing?

**EDIT:** Port security is disabled.

**EDIT:** When I ping from one machine to the other it says "Request Timed Out". That normally means it knows its there but can't send data.

Comment: It is curious that you are not allowed to add the configuration. What's the size? On the question itself do you see the MAC address of the devices in the MAC address table of the switch? Are they correctly seen on VLAN 2? Is it possible on this switch to add an IP on the VLAN2 interface  , like 192.168.2.103 and try to ping both hosts from the switch? Do you have anything in the switch log, for example a duplex mismatch notification? Did you check the cables?

Comment: @JFL I can't find the MAC address table on the switch. It doesn't have a CONSOLE port to console to it. On the web Interface I have checked to make sure the cables have good signal and that they are on the correct VLAN. I cannot add an IP to the VLAN2 itself as it would kick off access for VLAN1. Switch Log only shows that I have plugged in the computers to the switfch on those ports.

Comment: What is the switch model? There's no CLI? (SSH or even Telnet). Do you have another switch available to connect the 2 hosts on it to check if they can communicate?

Comment: @JFL This is a Black Box LGB2118A. I have another switch but I would have to pull it out of the rack and disconnect everyone.

Comment: it seems this model actually doesn't have any CLI and the manual mention the MAC address table as a concept, but doesn't mention any way to look at it. So we can only rely on testing various thing (changing the cable, testing with another switch, etc..). This is one reason why such devices are off-topic here (and why I would never consider buying one for a business environment).

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did set the VLANs correctly. Turns out to be an issue with Windows 10. When the computer detected the new network they did not ask if it was public or private and due to this they defaulted to public and so ping was blocked. Proved by disabling the public firewall. Sorry for the stupid answer but this was the issue.

Comment: Glad you found the issue, don't forget to accept your own answer (you should be able to do so after 48H I think) so it doesn't pop up forever looking for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

When ports 11 and 12 are members of the same untagged VLAN they should talk to each other.

On the switch, check the VLAN's MAC entries for both clients' MAC addresses. If one of them doesn't make it there's something wrong with the port or the NIC config.